# install cx_oracle for python on Mac OS

Tags: python, oracle, macos, cx-oracle

I cannot install cx_oracle neither by pip nor from sources. An error is the same.
From sources:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 174, in <module>
    raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation`

by pip:

```
pip install cx_oracle                          
Collecting cx_oracle
  Using cached cx_Oracle-5.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/private/var/folders/3w/q8kdj8j16h1_2d91_th3j6pc0000gn/T/pip-build-gva4v7dp/cx-oracle/setup.py", line 170, in 
        raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
    distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3w/q8kdj8j16h1_2d91_th3j6pc0000gn/T/pip-build-gva4v7dp/cx-oracle/
```

OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [Oracle Instant Client 12.1 Basic & SDK packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html), and set ORACLE_HOME to its location?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I thought that I installed it. But I didn't add its path to $PATH var.